# C - weird syntax error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing an application in ANSI C (Visual Studio 2010)
my library looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef _MYLIB_
#define _MYLIB_

typedef enum {false, true} bool;

// some structures and function prototypes...

#endif
```

I include this library in every .c file (I've got like 4 .c files - 1 main.c with main() and the rest with functions).

I get an error:

```
Generating Code...
1>  first.cpp
1>c:\users\A1\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pr1\pr1\mylib.h(7): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\users\A1\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pr1\pr1\mylib.h(7): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\A1\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pr1\pr1\mylib.h(7): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>  second.cpp
1>c:\users\A1\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pr1\pr1\mylib.h(7): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\users\A1\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pr1\pr1\mylib.h(7): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\A1\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pr1\pr1\mylib.h(7): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
```

What's more - when I paste all functions and structures into main.c - it works properly...
I have no idea how to fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly believe that you are interfering with the C++ built-in `false` and `true`, so you are trying to redefine them in your `enum`.

Try to replace `false` and `true` with `FALSE` and `TRUE` and `bool` with `BOOL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef _MYLIB_
#define _MYLIB_

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} BOOL;

// some structures and function prototypes...

#endif
```

Comment: yes, you're right :) Thank you very much :) I'll accept in 6 minutes.

Comment: You are welcome. This can be distressful if you don't know about it.